# Can you combine multi-value index with range scan

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-8.0

We are trying to use the new Multi-variable index (MVI) feature in MySQL 8.0.17 in order to optimize some problematic queries but are bumping into a issue where it won't use MVI-multi column indexes as we would need it to.

The underlying problem we are working with is one of "tags", such that we have a table with 2M rows where each row is "tagged" with 5-20 tags and the tags have a cardinality in the range of 0.001% to 20%. The structure can be described as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id int not null primary key,
  b int not null,
  c int not null
);
CREATE TABLE tags (
  tag_id int not null,
  data_id int not null,
  name char(16),
  primary key (tag_id, data_id),
  foreign key (data_id) references data (id)
);
```

Today we are creating a materialized view with `rows (2M) * tags (10) => 20M` rows where we can create indexes on tag+order. This however has the problem that we need to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY in order to remove duplicates when querying for multiple tags which in turn means that we have to choose between a order by-index or a group by-index. The following SQL is a simplification of the table structure and a extreme example of where we get problems.

```
create table mv_test (
    id int not null,
    tag_id int not null,
    b int not null,
    c int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, id),
    INDEX (b)
);
SELECT id FROM mv_test WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY id ORDER BY b LIMIT 100000, 1;
```

We are hoping to work around these issues using MVIs as follows.

```
create table mvi_test (
    id int auto_increment not null primary key,
    tag_ids json not null,
    b int not null,
    c int not null,
    INDEX idx1 ( (CAST(tag_ids->'$' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)), b )
);
SELECT id FROM mvi_test WHERE json_overlaps('[1,2,3]', tag_ids->'$') ORDER BY b LIMIT 100000, 1;
```

However we have not been able to create a index and query where both the MVI on `tag_ids` and the range on `b` is used.

We are seeing a few query parameters responding in different ways.

- Where the tags are very specific (eg less than 1000 rows) ordering is not a problem and the optimizer uses the MVI. (ie < 0.01s)
- Where the tags are very common (eg more than 20% of rows) the range index on `b` is sufficient and the MVI can be skipped and the queries are fast enough (ie 0.00s - 0.3s)
- Where the tags are moderately common (eg 5% of rows) and the offset is high MySQL still uses the range on `b` but discards most rows in reality doing a full table scan. (takes several seconds)

By forcing indexes we can manually tweak our example queries and get acceptable performance for most (ie less than 1s), however we can not find a way to determine which index to use for every combination of parameters. Also it seems that the optimizer is in a much better position to do this and it seems like a futile attempt to be smarter than it.

So the question is: can you create a multi column index where one part is a MVI and one is used for a range scan? Any other solutions to the more general problem is of course appreciated as well.